# Zombie Scramble keeps returning to life!

Tags: notifications, application-manager

Scramble, by Zynga (go figure), has apparently figured out how to re-enable notifications for itself without my interaction. I have turned off notifications in the application settings menu for android on my stock unrooted Galaxy S4 numerous times, but it somehow seems to turn itself back on within 24-48 hours.

So my question is in two parts:

1) As a programmer, I'm very curious, what method does Zynga use to continually re-enable notifications for Scramble?

2) How do I disable their re-enabling notifications?

Comment: Have there been any updates to the app?

Comment: If there's updates they're ones that don't require my approval. I've been watching for that because it would be so simple of a way around people disabling app notifications.

Comment: Have you by any chance moved this app to SD Card? I believe there is a bug that the "Show notifications" setting gets reset on reboot for apps that are moved to SD Card.

Comment: Ok, I disabled notifications while the app was on the SD storage, and rebooted which caused notifications to re-enable. I moved the app to the device storage, disabled the notifications, and rebooted which did not cause notifications to re-enable.

It looks like that SD card bug is the culprit. Thanks for the help and please put your suggestion in an answer so I can accept it. =)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is happening because of an issue (or a feature?) on stock Samsung firmware.  Whenever you reboot the phone, the "Show notifications" setting of apps that were moved to SD Card will revert to its original state, which is to allow notifications.

The work-around is to move the app back to the phone, and the setting will persist across reboots.

Comment: This bug affects vanilla Android 5.0.2 too, not just Samsung ROMs. If you have any more info, web links or better workarounds please comment back. I can imagine an app to plug this gap, which maintains a list of notification prefs, and "ensures" them upon system startup.